# Unable to save files to my apps Documents folder when running sandboxed

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsdata, sandbox

For some reason when running my app is running sandboxed, I'm unable to save files to my apps Documents folder.

Here's my method:

```
-(void) saveShotToDevice:(UIImage *)shot {
    // Get the documents directory  
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    NSString *imageFile = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Sequence%iShot%i.jpg",
                                                                                                             currentSequenceId, 
                                                                                                         currentSequenceShot]
                           ];

    currentSequenceShot++;

    NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(shot, 1.0);
    [imageData writeToFile:imageFile atomically:YES];
    [sequencesDB saveShot:currentSequenceId:imageFile];
}
```

And here's the console log

```
Nov  9 17:13:09 unknown sandboxd[176] <Notice>: Nabit(175) deny file-write-create /dh?ph?#,
Nov  9 17:13:10 unknown Nabit[175] <Warning>: Image path: /var/mobile/Applications/3F9A2648-B104-4D35-AD06-30A8F338096B/Documents/Sequence0Shot0.jpg
```

For some reasons the image path seems to be wrongly formatted in sandbox mode, but I really can't figure out why.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

It wasn't in the method I outline but in my `[sequencesDB saveShot:currentSequenceId:imageFile];` method.

The database was never sucessfully created in sandbox mode.